# How can I use gcc to compile x86 assembly code on an x64 computer

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, compiler-construction, x86-64

For a school assignment I have to write x86 assembly code, except I can't use gcc to compile it since my computer is an x64 machine, and gcc is only excpecting x86 code.  Is there a command that'll make gcc accept it x86 assembly code?  Thanks

P.S.  I know my code is valid since it compiles just fine on x86 machines.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just pass the `-m32` option to gcc.